# Are feed-based layouts limited to certain object?

Tags: page-layout, limits, configuration, chatter-feed

I am unable to get the assets page layout as a feed-based layout, is it possible that feed-based layout is limited to certain objects? I can't seem to find this limitation within the help documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bartley

the [salesforce help](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=feed_based_layouts_overview.htm&language=en_US) for Feed based Layout Overview says

*Feed-based layouts are available on **account, contact, lead, opportunity**, and custom objects.*

So i believe its available only for the 4 standard objects and for custom objects.
Any other standard object other than the 4 listed above might not have feed based layout.

additional reference : [Creating Feed Based Layout](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=create_feed_based_layouts.htm&language=en_US)

*You can create feed-based layouts for **account, contact, lead, opportunity**, and custom objects. To create feed-based layouts for cases, use Case Feed.*